# How to inform your would-be new employer in a proper business email that you have posted resignation from the current(would-be past) company?

Tags: resignation, email, employer

This may be unusual, but this thing just clicked in my mind. What should someone write in an email to inform their (would-be) new employer that they have posted their resignation from the current(soon would-be past) company. Also, a follow up could be a request to extend/delay the joining date(or start date, as it may be called) for some reasons? The email should be polite and is more of a request to delay the joining date. Nobody would like to be rude in the email, when a new partnership is about to begin.

Comment: That "would-be" sounds like the new job isn't quite locked in yet - are you sure you want to be leaving your current job before "will-be"?

Comment: @HorusKol : With 'would-be', I meant, that the person still hasn't joined it, but he would be joining it some days later. It is already 'locked-in'. And when the person joins it, the future employer(new) would thus become the current one! I hope I am able to make my point clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the UK it would go something like this:

"Hi Newboss,

Just to let you know that I've now handed in my notice, and I'll be ready to start with you guys on the *n*th of Octember. Really looking forward to getting started in the new role!

Kind regards,
Joe Smith"

and

"Hi Newboss, would it be ok for me to start a week later than we originally planned? Let me know, if it's a problem we can stick to the original date."

*but* it sounds from the tone of your question as though you're in a location where business English is more formal than here in the UK (I'm guessing India maybe?)

If that's the case then I suggest you amend your question to say the country/culture you're in, so you can get advice that's more specific to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. That looks polite and conveys the message as well.